# Why does each subsequent append to a tar archive take longer?

Tags: linux, tar, archiving

I am constructing a tar archive of size 4.2T in increments of ~440Gb. The timing to complete each of the increments (sections) is given below.

```
Section 1  [486.01 seconds]  
Section 2  [623.42 seconds]  
Section 3  [612.81 seconds]  
Section 4  [622.24 seconds]  
Section 5  [635.72 seconds]  
Section 6  [764.05 seconds]  
Section 7  [1115.31 seconds] 
Section 8  [1226.1 seconds]  
Section 9  [1331.82 seconds] 
Section 10 [1429.07 seconds]
```

The times in the brackets reflect the time it takes to write each section (i.e. it's not cumulative). Why is it that in general each subsequent append takes longer to write the same amount of data than the previous? This is a major issue for me because I have to create multi terabyte tar files and I want to understand the bottlenecks so that I can speed up the creation and extraction of archives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that GNU *tar* takes longer because it is *scanning the entire original archive* before appending. This seems like it should be done only for `--update` since most of the code is about removing old file versions, but for some reason it's also done for `--append` and `--catenate` as well. (See the update_archive() function in the source code.)

The `bsdtar` command from [libarchive](https://www.libarchive.org/) does not do so; it just immediately appends the new data.

Comment: Oh this is interesting. Thanks. I'll check with the Bsdtar version to see the differences. Do you know if there is a reason GNU tar does that, or is it just an anachronism that hasn't been fixed?

Comment: Not sure; it has always done so as far as Git history reaches. I'm guessing it comes from the fact that tar was originally for _tape_ archives, and it would have to manually seek the tape until the end of the archive before appending. (Of course, it can be optimized away when dealing with files, where the end is known.) However, I can't quite decipher the libarchive/bsdtar source, it _seems_ like it's supposed to also scan the entire archive as well?

Comment: Bsdtar indeed starts appending almost instantly. Thanks!

Comment: That being said, is a terabyte-sized archive really a wise idea?

Comment: These are climate model simulation outputs, the constituent files themselves are very big. The archives are backed up to actual tapes.